# Triggering intent from a listview item in volley

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-volley

I am parsing json using volley and am getting the desire values but, I am unable to trigger intents to pass list item values to another activity. I am able to toast a variable though

here is my code

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // Get the position
        Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(activity, String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SingView.class);
        // Pass all data rank
        intent.putExtra("hek", "hi");
        // Pass all data country
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
return convertView;
```

the above approach force closes my app. Is this the right approach or am I making a mistake? Here in my code toast texts work without any glitch.

Comment: why dont you use listview.setOnItemClickListner() for clicking an item in listview.

Comment: show us the exception